# Laravel 8.x - How to use updateOrCreate with a where clause?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to use Laravel `updateOrCreate` to update a record if its within this month and last month based on if an ID exists.

```
\App\Models\Result::updateOrCreate(
        [
            'id' => $request->get('id'),
            // where created_at is within the last 2 months
            'created_at' => [
                '>',
                \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->subMonthsNoOverflow()
            ],
        ],
        [
            'discipline_one' => $request->get('d-one'),
            'discipline_two' => $request->get('d-two'),
            'discipline_three' => $request->get('d-three'),
            'discipline_four' => $request->get('d-four'),
            'discipline_five' => $request->get('d-five'),
            'discipline_six' => $request->get('d-six'),
        ]
    );
```

If the ID exists, and the result is in this current month or last, a new record is created instead of updated.

> Expected input: 1 (which exists from last month) 
> Expected output: Record is updated

> Expected input: 2 (which doesn't exist or is not within 2 months) 
> Expected output: New record is created

Update:

Using the answer suggested,

```
'id' => $request->get('id'),
'created_at' => \App\Models\Result::whereBetween('created_at', [
    \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->subMonthsNoOverflow(),
    \Carbon\Carbon::now()->endOfMonth(),
]),
```

I get the error:

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

You only need to ***explicitly*** define the *operators* in the method's first parameter.

Each element of the array in the method's first parameter should be an array containing the three arguments.
*column, operator, value*

```php
$startDate = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->subMonths(2);
$endDate = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->endOfMonth();

$resultRow = \App\Models\Result::query()
        ->where('id', $request->id)
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])
        ->first();

\App\Models\Result::updateOrCreate(
    [
        [
            'id', '=', $request->get('id'),
        ],
        [
            'created_at', '>=', $startDate,
        ],
        [
            'created_at', '<=', $endDate,
        ],
    ],

    array_merge(
        [
            'discipline_one' => $request->get('d-one'),
            'discipline_two' => $request->get('d-two'),
            'discipline_three' => $request->get('d-three'),
            'discipline_four' => $request->get('d-four'),
            'discipline_five' => $request->get('d-five'),
            'discipline_six' => $request->get('d-six'),
        ],

        $resultRow ? [] : [
            'id' => $request->get('id'),
            'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()
        ]
    )

);
```

Notice that I repeated `id` & `created_at` column settings in the method's second parameter. It's because contrary to the regular behaviour, a merge of the 2 method's parameter arrays wasn't performed based on my tests if no result was found with that criteria.

Comment: Laravel has had a global helper function `now()` for a long time. You should be doing date subtraction first, then use start of month. E.g. `now()->subMonths(2)->startOfMonth()`.